# Type of variable returns false even if I cast it to the exact same class

Tags: types, casting, flutter

I do not understand why the line `print(item is MyClass);` line in the build function returns false for all items.

As you can see the List is of MyClass items, and when I get the item of index I cast it to MyClass. Still the print line code returns false.

This is the code of the widget:

```
import ...;

class _ListTheatreState extends State<ListTheatre> {
  List<MyClass> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getEvents();
  }

  _getEvents() async {
    final url = '...';
    try {
      http.Response res = await http.get(url);
      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      this.items = data["data"];
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final MyClass item = items[index];
        print(item is MyClass); // **<-- RETURNS FALSE**
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}

class ListTheatre extends StatefulWidget {
  ListTheatre({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListTheatreState createState() => _ListTheatreState();
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough code to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: But I do not why If I cast item to MyClass, after the item variable is not of MyClass type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.decode doesn't know how to magically create your object type. Without the json it's impossible to tell what exactly is being returned but I assume a json object, which in dart will be a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. You're casting it to MyClass, which doesn't fail because dart assumes that if you're casting something you've checked the type beforehand. If you were to then use the `item` object, I'm fairly sure it will throw some sort of exception. It's returning false because the object is of type Map not MyClass. Try printing item.runtimeType - it should give you a better idea.

What you're going to need to do is parse the json and use it to create instances of MyClass. You can either do that manually or use the code generation. See flutter's [json docs](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).